# Lazy load in Web API Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I am having issues with the lazy loading. I have the following dbcontext.

```
public virtual DbSet<AccountGroupMst> AccountGroupMst {get; set;}
```

I have enabled the lazy loading.

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(x => 
                x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Test"))
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies());
```

Model, I have virtual and it is a self referencing table.

```
public class AccountGroupMst
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int AccountGroupId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required]
    public string AccountGroupName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentAccountGroupId")]
    public  int? ParentAccountGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountGroupMst ParentGroup { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have is, the Entity framework returns all the children.

```
{
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "parentGroup": {
                "parentGroup": {
                    "parentGroup": null,
                    "accountGroupId": 1,
                    "name": "Test 2.1",
                    "parentAccountGroupId": null
                },
                "accountGroupId": 5,
                "name": "Test 1.1",
                "parentAccountGroupId": 1
            },
            "accountGroupId": 18,
            "name": "Test",
            "parentAccountGroupId": 5
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is if lazy load enabled, it is not supposed to display the 'Test 1.1 and Test 2.1'. Please let me know if I am making anything wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy loading will only get the values when they are accessed. When spitting out the JSON, the properties are accessed and the values are retrieved by EF Core as a separate query. Hence, it's not recommended to use lazy loading with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to say "it's not recommended to use lazy loading with ASP.NET Core"? Or did you mean "returning JSON data for a Web API"?

Comment: @Svek yes. lazy loading is bad because it loads values via separate queries.

Comment: Just to clarify again, you are saying ASP.NET Core + Lazy Loading = Bad? An entire framework?

Comment: I'm having a hard time agreeing with that kind of statement.

Comment: I think the problem is when I say "lazy loading" I mean a design pattern. You might be referring to it only within the context of handling a request and serving data via EF.

Comment: @Svek which is the context of this question

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks. What would be the best approach if we don't want to load the parent group?  I am so if it is dump question. Thanks

Comment: @SureshKannan try turning off lazy loading. Perhaps you should share your query

Comment: here is the code:  

     public async Task<IEnumerable<AccountGroupMst>> ViewAllAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var acgroups = await _db.AccountGroupMst.ToListAsync();
                return acgroups;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
         
        }

Comment: Surprised to hear that I'm discouraged to keep lazy loading with WebAPI but I understand why. What would you suggest as an alternative? A set of DTOs?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana carefully crafted queries