# Can't configure lazy loading in EF Core 2.2 to cut off unloaded parts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I'm getting the following content when I invoke my API. It kind of breaks up in the middle when the tenant entity that member is linked to, will start listing its member entities.

> {
>   "id":"00000000-7357-000b-0001-000000000000",
>   "tenantId":"00000000-7357-000a-0001-000000000000",
>   "userName":"user1",
>   "tenant":{
>   "id":"00000000-7357-000a-0001-000000000000",
>   "name":"First Fake Org",
>   "members":[

I configured the lazy loading like this.

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(config => config
  .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
  .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Register")));
```

How should I change the code so that the lazily loaded entities don't get served? I was hoping that it would simply return an empty list to the client. Should I use a DTO for that purpose and not return from the DB like this? There's talk about not using lazy loading for APIs at all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163195/8744999).

```
[HttpGet("test1/{username}"), AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult GetStuff(string userName)
{
  Member output;

  output = Context.Members
    .Include(e => e.Tenant)
    .Single(e => e.UserName == userName);

  return Ok(output);
}
```

I'm not sure what to google for and all the hits I got were pointing to the `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` invokation.

Comment: If you are return a lazy loaded instance then you are instantiating that list<T>. If you just want an empty list<T> then return a `new List<Members>();` although I'm not sure what the practical application would be from what you have shown.

Comment: @AustinTFrench Sorry for being unclear. I'm returning an instance of a member (`Single()` invokation). That member has its tenant. The tenant has, of course, a list of members that the retrieved member is a part of. I want the list of the tenant to be empty (or not visible at all) as it's not going to be used.

Comment: OK, so you have a members object which has a tenant property, which also has a List<Members> or similar and you only want that first layer ?  Essentially Members.Single(s => s.UserName == userName ) and **not** any child properties?

Comment: @AustinTFrench That is correctly understood. The way I approached it is by having an instance of `MemberOutput` and create it with `output` as a parameter passed in. In the constructor, I map whatever props I want to keep and omit whatever is double-layered. Given the number of props and variation, I sense I'm doing it more mundane than it needs to be. Configuring an auto-mapper is a bit overkill at this moment, though. An I doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably be somewhat long winded: But here goes.

It sounds like you have Entities which look something like:

```
public partial class Member
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }  //tables have fk relationship
}


 public partial class Tenant
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Member> Members{ get; set; }  //tables have another fk relationship?
}
```

And then for this method:

```
[HttpGet("test1/{username}"), AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult GetStuff(string userName)
{
  Member output;

  output = Context.Members
    .Include(e => e.Tenant)
    .Single(e => e.UserName == userName);

  return Ok(output);
}
```

I see a few issues, but I'll try to keep it short:

I wouldn't have the controller do this directly. But it should work.

What I think you over looked is exactly what the .Include statement does. When the object is instantiated, it will get all of those related entities. Includes essentially converts your where statement to a left join, where the foreign keys match (EF calls these navigation properties).

If you don't want the Tenant property, then you can omit the .Include statement. Unless this is meant to be more generic (In which case, an even stronger reason to use a different pattern and auto mapper).

Hopefully your database doesn't truly have a FK relationship both ways, if it does, fix that ASAP.

The next issue is that you might not want a list of child properties, but it is in the model so they will be "there". Although your List Tenants might be `null`. And while this might be fine to you, right now. As a general rule when I see an API returning a property, I expect something to be either not there (This Member doesn't have tenants) or something is wrong, like perhaps there is a second parameter I missed. This probably isn't a problem 93.284% of the time, but it is something to be mindful of.

This starts to get into why an AutoMapper is great. Your Database Models, Business Models and views are likely different. And as much as you shouldn't return the database models directly. Taking control of how the data is represented for each part of the application is a great idea.

You could reduce the code easily, and remove the navitation properties:

```
[HttpGet("test1/{username}"), AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult GetStuff(string userName)
{   
  return Ok(Context.Members
    .Include(e => e.Tenant)
    .Single(e => e.UserName == userName));    
}
```

But again, a business layer would be better:

```
[HttpGet("test1/{username}"), AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult GetStuff(string userName)
{
  return Ok(MemberRepository.GetMember(userName));
}
```

The main point I'd stress though, is creating a view model.

For example, Let's say a user Detail:

```
public class MemberDetail
{
   public string UserName {get; set;}
   public long UserId { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

This way the view *always* receives exactly what you want to see, and not the extra data. Add this with the fact that you can know exactly how every use of `Member` to `MemberDetail` will map.

Comment: That's the solution I went for. I have currently three sets of objects. One is the business model as recognized by the EF working against my DB. The model-model, so to speak. Then, I have a set of view-models (as you suggested) that I manually populate with the exact data that's going to be required for rendition of the page. Finally, I have a feed-back-model, i.e. objects that the client populates with data and reports back to the API. At first, I thought of having the VM classes and DTO classes the same but it makes less sense.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I have done a similar thing as well from time to time, especially when I am posting complext types that span business models.

Comment: The OP is still not convinced about that, though. We work together on this but we have disagreements regarding the modelling issues. Would you be willing to pass a word on the 2-models vs 3-models choice? His idea is to use the same object structure to provide data to the client (view-models) and to receive data from the client (data-tranfers). I claim that we rarely will manipulate the emitted object.

Comment: Would you be able to mention that in the answer so we can remove the comments all together?